# Connect internal numbers on freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I would like to connect two internal numbers with one, I mean if I call 499 then two phones should ring for example 123, 127. 
My .xml files in directory/default looks like this:

```
<include>
<user id="127" mailbox="127">
<params>
  <param name="password" value="xxxx"/>
  <param name="vm-password" value="127"/>
</params>
<variables>
  <variable name="toll_allow" value="domestic,international,local"/>
  <variable name="accountcode" value="127"/>
  <variable name="user_context" value="default"/>
  <variable name="effective_caller_id_name" value="Extension 127"/>
  <variable name="effective_caller_id_number" value="127"/>
  <variable name="outbound_caller_id_name" value="$${outbound_caller_name}"/>
  <variable name="outbound_caller_id_number" value="$${outbound_caller_id}"/>
  <variable name="callgroup" value="techsupport"/>
</variables>
```

similar for 123 and 499 numbers. 
How can I change it to make two phones rings(123,127) when someone calls 499?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your dialplan you should call the bridge application like this.

```
<extension name="Local_Extension">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(1001)$">
            <action application="bridge" data="sofia/internal/1001%${server-domain-name},sofia/internal/1002%${server-domain-name},sofia/internal/1003%${server domain-name}"/>
    </condition>
</extension>
```

- So if you call to 1001 then it will ring to 1001,1002,1003

Comment: Generally it works but it blocks the rest of phones. That's mean I can call 1001 but when trying to call another number for example 1003 then it's fail all the time. So I'll give you plus but don't accept the answer.

Comment: Well I made new extension cause the Local_Extension already exists. Can it create any problems?

Comment: hi for that you just have to change logic of dialplan condition like that accept 1001 or 1002 or 1003.

Comment: You should give different name to extension.